# How to return one by one from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have arraylist say,

```
List<CalendarOutput> RecuringEve= Recurrent.eventView(component,begin,end);
```

and i want to print the arraylist,

```
CalendarOutput caldavOutput = ListUtil.getReComponent(component, RecuringEve);
```

here i have method getReComponent(component, RecuringEve)

```
public CalendarOutput getReComponent(Component component, List recuringEve) {
for(int i = 0; i < recuringEve.size(); i++)   {  
  CalendarOutput.DTSTART_FULL=recuringEve.get(i).toString();
 }
retrun CalendarOutput;
}
```

This method must return value one by one. but it return only the last value of the Arraylist. how can return value one by one

Comment: What is "retrun"? Why are you returning `CalendarOutput`, where is it declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method returns only **once**. You cannot make it return many times, but you can **invoke a method** many times. And if you want to return many values, you can simply collect these values in a **list / collection** and then return that **list / collection**.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to do a method. You can use For each to print the arraylist.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<CalendarOutput> RecuringEve= Recurrent.eventView(component,begin,end);
    CalendarOutput caldavOutput = ListUtil.getReComponent(component, RecuringEve);

    System.out.print("Original contents of vals: ");
    for (int v : caldavOutput)
      System.out.print(v + " ");
  }
}
```

[Credit java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util/foreachloopforArrayList.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
public CalendarOutput getReComponent(Component component, List recuringEve) {
for(int i = 0; i < recuringEve.size(); i++)   {
  // Do you just want to append? then use +=
  CalendarOutput.DTSTART_FULL+=recuringEve.get(i).toString();
 }
retrun CalendarOutput;
}
```